# Flutter TextField: How add icon in right

Tags: flutter

in InputDecoration section on TextField Widget only icon for left is available(i mean outside of textfield not suffix)

how i add icon in right TextField?

for use Row its another problem:

```
 body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Text("Hi")
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: Row(
            children: [
              TextField(
                style: TextStyle(
                  backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(118, 118, 128, 0.35),
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Message",
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(235, 235, 245, 0.6),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your custom Textfield ,like below code:

```
Container(
          child: Row(
        children: [Flexible(child: TextField()), Icon(Icons.add)],
      )),
```

Comment: thanks.i know it.but please see my part 2 questions.i cant use Row.its give me error

Answer (score 3):

**USE 'suffixIcon'.**

As 'prefixIcon' allows you to apply icon in the left side of TextField.
You can use 'suffixIcon' for icon in the right side of TextField.

Happy Coding .

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `Expanded` in the first place? But if it's a must, I think you can do it like this :

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Text("Hi")
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
              height: 35,
              child: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(
                  backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(118, 118, 128, 0.35),
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Message",
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(235, 235, 245, 0.6),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Icon(Icons.add_a_photo, size: 25)
          ],
        )
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Your code gives an error because the `Textfield` needs sizes.

Comment: But now the `TextField` is limited in size and this is not good for responsive design. And it may looks differently on different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Flexible(
      child: TextField(
        style: TextStyle(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(118, 118, 128, 0.35),
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Message",
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(235, 235, 245, 0.6),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(width: 10.0),
    Icon(Icons.settings),
  ],
),
```

It is required to limit the `TextField` with `Flexible` widget. `Flexible` acts for `TextField` like `MainAxisSize.min` for `Column`.

Comment: its not work for me.bcs i use Expandad in Column

Comment: It works because it creates row with textfield and icon. Yoy need just tweek your code to use Expanded/Flexible.

Comment: @nimanima , I've fixed the code. now working.